# Flex Mobile Project: Open PDF in Native Reader on iOS

Tags: ios, apache-flex, pdf, mobile, native

I'm developing a Flex Mobile Project for iPad (iOS) and I need to open a PDF document in the native PDF reader.

I think I need integrate with a Native Extension.

Someone did something like that?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Can't you just link to the PDF with navigateToURL?  That, basically, hands the request off to the operating system to handle.  I believe it should open either in the device's native reader [or possibly in the browser?]

Comment: It work ok for external files, but doesnt for local files, and that is my case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
var myFileName:String = 'myFile.pdf';
var localFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('myAppFolder/'+myFileName);
localFile.openWithDefaultApplication()
```

Maybe this can help you!